# Foreign key creation issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have followed this article: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html to create a foreign key between two tables. Every single attempt fails. Is there anything that I am missing?!

It's really frustrating and I never expected to encounter this issue at all!

Thanks.

Comment: ... could you show us what exactly your attempts are?

Answer (score 3):

You don't show what you tried or what the error was, so all of the answers are only guesswork.

Here's a checklist of things that must be true before foreign keys can work:

- InnoDB storage engine must be enabled.

  ```
  mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_innodb';
  ```
- Both tables must use the InnoDB storage engine (MyISAM doesn't support referential integrity constraints).

  ```
  mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE <parent_table>;
  mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE <child_table>;
  ```
- The column(s) in the referenced table must be the leftmost column(s) of a key. Typically this is the PRIMARY KEY, but InnoDB actually allows them to be part of *any* key.
- The foreign key column and its referenced primary key column must be of **exactly** the same data type (must match signed vs. unsigned, int vs. bigint, string charset, etc.). Only the string length is allowed to be different.
- You have to get the [constraint declaration syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) right.  :-)
- If you're adding a constraint to a populated table, all the existing values must satisfy the constraint (thanks to Jordan S. Jones' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963119/foreign-key-creation-issue-in-mysql/963143#963143) on this thread).

Comment: This is the order in which I would trouble shoot the key creation.

Comment: +1. I must say I always enjoy your answers. They are thorough and very knowledgeable.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize to watch out for signed vs unsigned. Easy to overlook and caught me.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is going wrong? We can't really help you without details...

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE parent (id INT NOT NULL,
    ->                      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> CREATE TABLE child (id INT, parent_id INT,
    ->                     INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    ->                     FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
    ->                       ON DELETE CASCADE
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have to remember, that if you're child table/column has values that don't exist in the parent table/column, you will always get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
use trading_research;
drop table if exists stock_history;
create table stock_history
(
        company_id integer(4) NOT NULL,
        price_date date NOT NULL,
        primary key(company_id, price_date),
        opening_price decimal(10,2) NULL,
        closing_price decimal(10,2) NULL,
        high_price decimal(10,2) NULL,
        low_price decimal(10,2) NULL,
        adjusted_closing_price decimal(10,2) NULL,
        volume decimal(20, 2) NULL,
        constraint foreign key (company_id) references stock_company (company_id) on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

If you give details of what you're trying and/or the errors you get, I can help more.